# django south migration: can I pass a parameter to the forward method?

Tags: python, django, django-south

It is basically all in the title: it is possible to pass a parameter to the south forward method? Now the method looks like this:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding model 'Chk'
        db.create_table(u'chk', (
            (u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
            ('chk_original_pk', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField')()),
            ('chk_original_geom', self.gf('django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.GeometryField')(srid=28992, null=True, blank=True)),
            ('chk_name', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=255)),
))
```

What I want to archive is something like this:

```
    def forwards(self, orm, srid):
        # Adding model 'Chk'
        db.create_table(u'chk', (
            (u'id', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.AutoField')(primary_key=True)),
            ('chk_original_pk', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField')()),
            ('chk_original_geom', self.gf('django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.GeometryField')(srid=srid, null=True, blank=True)),
            ('chk_name', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(max_length=255)),
))
```

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do it.  As far as I can tell, you would just have to edit the migration with the SRID you want

Comment: well, the thing is the SRID is variable...;-)

Comment: Wouldn't you have to know the SRID when the table is created?  I don't think your database is going to let you not specify an SRID.  I think you just have to pick one, and transform your geometry to that projection.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: It is quit a complex setup with hundreds of different databases. Now the srid is read from models.py but could actually be different for the database that is being migrated.

Comment: Could you put it in settings, and import django.conf.settings into your migration?

Comment: yeah, I'll find a different solution. Thanks anyway